# How can I connect Access 2013 Database to SQL Server (linked tables) Using ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I'm working with a client for whom we're trying to link SQL Server tables to Access. Simple enough, right? The problem is that the machine is running Office 2013 on Windows 7. The SQL Server is, I believe, SQL 2017 (99% sure of this).

Yet no matter what I try, SQL Server native, ODBC 11, ODBC 13, using the same Windows Integrated authentication that I'm able to use successfully in SQL Server Management Studio, I cannot create an ODBC connection (either user, or system, or file), it always tells me "Server Not Found"

By request, the full error message. I have to type this manually so (the error message comes from the ODBC Create Data Source...

```
Connection Failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: -1
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server] SQL Server Network
Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]
Connection Failed:
SQLState: 'HYT00'
SQL Server Error: 0
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired.
```

So here are more specifics:
I am remoting into a Windows 7 Desktop. Call this PC#1
We connect to SQL Server through Remote Desktop Connection (SQL Server is not installed on this machine) Call this PC#2

If I log on to PC#2 using remote desktop connection (the machine where SQL Server is actually installed) I can create the ODBC connection with no problem.

However, the Access is installed on PC#1. If I try to connect to the SQL Server database by using PC2\SQLEXPRESS, that's when we get the error.

DETAILS:
Operating System: Windows 7
Office 2013
SQL Server 2017 (via Remote Desktop) - I can connect to this no problem in SSMS using the same integrated security credentials that I'm trying here.

This is something I can do in my sleep in Access 2016 and Windows 10, but I'm running out of ideas fast. Any ideas?

Comment: `Server Not Found` - where this message comes from? - please [edit] your question with the full error description.

Comment: [Tcp-ip and named pipes enabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working)? Firewall ports opened.? ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server supports only sql sever 2014. Use at least ODBC Driver 13.1 ! You should hire an expert, as even client has limited knowledge (driver-version) and you are aware of WIn7 being EOL ( use in company enviroment is negligent!)

Comment: Yes I heard it was coming to an end soon but it's a moot point. if it were up to me I'd have Win10 with latest security patches and Office 2016, but unfortunately it's a client's environment I have no control over. They're "in the process" of upgrading all of their machines to Win10 but this is what I have to deal with for now.

We decide we're going to download EVERYTHING to my local computer that does have everything up to date including Win16, link the tables, then re-send the front end. Not elegant but until they upgrade it's the best we can do for now.

Comment: The idea that windows xp, win7 etc. makes a difference here is moot. But,  what is the connection string you are using on pc1? (and how did you manage to leave out that detail????). And does using SQL logons work on pc2, and NOT using windows authentication? (since that VERY unlikely to work from pc1).

Comment: The other huge massive issue? Can other computers on the network connect to sql server?